# Visual Form Inheritance - Changes in Baseform

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

I'm having a problem understanding VFI in Delphi2009.  If I change my layout in the baseform, those changes are not propagated to the inherited form.  For example, replacing a DBNavigator in the baseform with buttons has no effect on inherited forms.  Is there any way to accomplish this? Or do I have to re-implement all my inherited forms?

Answer (score 4):

Make sure that you reopen the child forms in the ide after changing the base form.  Otherwise they may not see the changes that you make

In your case, you should also check that you only have one copy of the base form.  If you have a copy of the base form somewhere, your child forms might be looking at the wrong base.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the 2009 version but changing controls in the base Form should certainly show up. But Properties can be overridden.

Are you sure you are using VFI and not templates?

Comment: I created a baseform, then selected "Inheritable Items", selected "BaseForm" and "inherit". For some reason this does not seem to work.

Comment: Take a look at the the class declaration of the derived, and maybe post a few lines here. And try to reproduce in a new Application.